# Power BI DAX formula to get results from previous row

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have data in Excel with 6 columns as attached in the image.

[image: Excel data]

I have applied the formula in the Output column-

```
`=IF(([673]-249)<0,[673]-178,[673]-249)`/ `=IF(([@GT]-E2)<0,[@GT]-D2,[@GT]-E2)`= I got the output- 424.
```

I have the same data in Power BI. Please help me with the formula to get the output column data.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best option, but it works. I used an additional column `ID`. This is the formula for a new calculated column which can be put to your report:

```
Output = 
VAR _id = Table1[ID]
VAR _gt = Table1[GT]
VAR _row0 = FILTER(Table1,[ID]=_id-1)
VAR _gt0 = MINX(_row0,[GT])
VAR _rng0 = MINX(_row0,[Range])
VAR _result1 = _gt - _gt0
RETURN IF( Table1[ID]=1,BLANK(), IF( _result1<0, _gt - _rng0, _result1) )
```

[image]